# In Tkinter The grid method when using on an input is not working.Why?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the input to be somewhere in the bottom of the screen but when I am using the grid method the position on the input is not changing.Why?

```
# Import module
from tkinter import *

# Create object
root = Tk()

# Adjust size
root.geometry( "5000x5000" )

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=10, column=1,sticky=W)

# Execute tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: there are no other widgets in the grid, so how would it know where the row 10 should be?

Comment: So how may i place the input widget at bottom of the window?

Comment: Grid rows only have any height or width if you have widgets in them, therefore your first 10 rows have a pixel height of 0

Comment: So @ChristyKail how can i place the input widget at the bottom of the window?

Comment: use `pack`: `e1.pack(side='bottom')` (btw rows and columns start from 0 not 1), if you insist on using `grid`: `root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and then `e1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='s')`, also don't use `*` when importing

Comment: @Matiiss sir actually i dont want the widget to be at absolute bottom.It should maintain some distance from the bottom

Comment: use `pady` option (that both layout managers have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid rows only have any height or width if you have widgets in them Therefore your first 10 rows have a pixel height of 0, causing row 10 to be placed on y = 0.
By setting the `column weight` to a non zero value, and setting the `sticky` to `S` you can pin the widget to the bottom of the root container:

```py
# Import module
from tkinter import Tk, Entry

# Create object
root = Tk()

# Adjust size
root.geometry("500x500")

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="S")

# Execute tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you shouldn't import everything

Comment: Just making it match the question as close as possible, changing other things can cause confusion in my experience, but feel free to edit to a more efficient import.

Comment: all that is needed in this case is to replace `*` with `Tk, Entry`

Comment: sir on my side when using this exact same code the window is appearing to be blank.no input is getting displayed

Comment: @KushagraJain are you still using 5000x5000 pixels? I would assume that the input box is off the bottom of your screen if so...

Comment: yea actually i wanted the window should cover the whole screen of the computer so i have used 5000x5000 pixels

Comment: @KushagraJain for that you can use `root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`, if you want the window to be fullscreen

Comment: And set your window size to your screen resolution, eg `1920x1080`

Comment: @Matiiss sir by using this cammand the window dont leave the space for cross button.Actually i the software which i am creating is for villages so i m trying to create this software as simple as possible

Comment: sorry, use `root.state('zoomed')`, also geometry doesn't matter when using these options

Comment: @Matiiss this command is working but still the input is getting displayed at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @KushagraJain this is precisely what your question asked for ...

Comment: While this technically answers the question, it's probably not the right answer if you're going to add more widgets above this widget.